# FBNativeDialogNotSupported Facebook sdk 3.1

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

With the release of Facebook SDK 3.1 it has a class which launches the Facebook Native Dialog for Post in iOS 6.

Below is the code for it.

```
[FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:currentController initialText:nil image:nil url:nil handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
 //Print Error
                    }];
```

Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 7.)" UserInfo=0x1e5e0930 {com.facebook.sdk:NativeDialogReasonKey=com.facebook.sdk:NativeDialogNotSupported

So, I tried to login first using the following code and then launch the FBNativeDialog. But, it does not enter the completion handler, when ***Okay*** button is pressed of Facebook permission window in Safari.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil]];


                    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                        switch (status) {
                            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                            [FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:currentController initialText:nil image:nil url:nil handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
                        NSLog(@"Dialog Error= %@",error);
                    }];
                                break;

                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }];
```

Comment: have you configured a facebook account?

Comment: Here is code which I tried further http://pastebin.com/nx89KxaJ

Answer (score 1):

> when Okay button is pressed of Facebook permission window in Safari

You need to set up the Facebook account on the iOS 6 device/simulator in order to use the native share dialogs. Once you have done so, you will get native iOS permissions dialogs as well so there should be no app switching to Safari to login. See my similar response to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/12681352/1712979